# How do I get detected boxes on evaluation set for tensorflow's object detection API?

Tags: tensorflow, computer-vision, deep-learning, object-detection, resnet

I was working with the recently released Tensorflow's API for object detection, with Faster RCNN on Resnet 101 on my own dataset. It seems to train and evaluate on Validation data, but I was hoping if there was a way I could get/store bounding boxes for all images in the Eval set, in a file, or maybe, get the location in the source code where I can get the predicted bounding boxes with image names.

Answer (score 1):

If you just want to obtain the detected bounding boxes given a set of images, the Jupyter notebook contains a good example of how to do this.

Comment: which notebook?

Comment: This is the notebook --- I think it's a pretty good example of how the results should be interpreted: https://github.com/tensorflow/models/blob/master/object_detection/object_detection_tutorial.ipynb

Comment: This link does not exist